# Importing extern declaration from other Cython declaration file

Tags: python, c, cython

I am writing a Cython extension for use in Python.

I have this Cython declaration .pxd file that declares a C struct that is defined in other C header file:

```
# Cython definitions for parameters.h
cdef extern from "parameters.h":
    ctypedef struct control_par:
        int num_cams
        # some other struct fields....
```

now I want to do the same thing for other header file but here I will have to use what I already defined above: the `control_par` C struct in another Cython `.pxd` file:

```
from optv cimport parameters, calibration # no error here during setup
cdef extern from "optv/trafo.h":
    void pixel_to_metric(# some other parameters...
                         control_par * parameters);
```

during cythonizing I get this error:

> 'control_par' is not a type identifier

like it was not defined at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to import C definitions is `parameters.control_par`. I would do:

```
from optv.parameters cimport control_par, whatever_else_you_need
```